# make the gmail web application default to English on login

Tags: gmail, localization

When I am abroad, everytime I go to Gmail, it does not respect my browsers user agent, which has the `Accept-Language` request header set to `en-US`.

Since my computers language is set to English, my browser is set to English, yet Google thinks I speak the language of the place I am currently in.

How can I force Gmail to speak English?

Is this possible? Maybe using a query parameter or some other mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

After inspecting what happens when i select the language from the dropdown on the login screen using Firefox devtools. I noticed that the "hl:en" parameter gets passed to the first request.

Then i put hl=en in the querystring for the gmail login url and bookmarked the page, that seems to bring me to the English Gmail.

This solution is sufficient for me.